# PyDev Package Explorer doesn't show files in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have been working for weeks using Eclipse's PyDev (Eclipse 3.8.1) and usually I click on files in Package Explorer to navigate through them. Now all of a sudden my Python project looks empty in the Package Explorer, just showing standard python libs.

I tried many things such as:

- Refreshing project.
- Importing again project to workspace.
- Looking at custom filters in "customize view".
- Opening project file in the editor and then using "link with editor".
- Closing PyDev Package Explorer and opening it again.
- Closing and opening Eclipse again (several times).

None of those showed the files. I don't know what is wrong with this project. I think it is not related, but it is also a git project.

Do you know what else is missing for me to try?

Thanks.

Comment: if you do Navigate -> Open Resource, do the files show up there?

Comment: No, the matching items in open resource shows empty.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project from scratch? Maybe even copy over files into the new project and the re-version it via git again?

Comment: That worked, I created a new directory, copied source files, and removed old project from Eclipse. It seems the project data was broken somehow.

Answer (score 14):

Found the solution in [PyDev FAQ](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhynothingshowsinthePyDevPackageExplorer%3F)

The usual checks are:

1. In the PyDev Package Explorer menu, is the top level elements pointing to working sets, if yes, change it to "Project".
2. In the PyDev Package Explorer menu, customize view, the content has both, PyDev Navigator Content and Resources checked?
3. In the PyDev Package Explorer menu, customize view, is it possible that the filters selected are hiding all your elements?

The first item solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. You could create a new working set and select the projects that you have created and wish to see them in the PyDev Package Explorer. This trick worked for me.

Steps to create a working set :

1. Click on the inverted triangle in the PyDec Package explorer.
2. Select "Select Working Set"
3. Click New button.
4. Select Resources and click Next
5. Select the projects that you wish to have them seen on the explorer -> mention a name of the working set and click Finish button.